# Manipulate coupled with QueueProperties

Tags: manipulate

I am trying to couple Manipulate with QueueProperties and it does not seem to work. It creates the manipulate screen but it is not dynamic. It just sits there.

Here is my example:

```
\[ScriptCapitalQ] = QueueingProcess[\[Lambda], 4.3, 1]
```

then I add:

```
Manipulate[QueueProperties[\[ScriptCapitalQ]], {\[Lambda], 1, 4}]
```

and it creates the Manipulate framework, but lambda does not change dynamically and recompute the QueueProperties.

Comment: I edited your question for you and added code formatting. To learn how to properly format your question yourself please have a look [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)

Comment: With `Manipulate[]` you generally want to have your expression being a function of the parameters that you want to manipulate. E.g. try `\[ScriptCapitalQ][\[Lambda]_] := QueueingProcess[\[Lambda], 4.3, 1]` and accordingly `Manipulate[QueueProperties[\[ScriptCapitalQ][\[Lambda]]], {\[Lambda], 1, 4}]`

Answer (score 2):

As Sascha has note in a comment, you need to define your queueing process as a function of `λ`.

```
q[λ_] := QueueingProcess[λ, 4.3, 1]
Manipulate[
  QueueProperties[q[λ]],
  {λ, 1, 4, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: process]